# How to check and control previous url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a multi-step form. There are steps like : step 1 , step 2 ... step 5.

How can i check people should follow this steps ? Is there a way to check if he comes from previous-true url(step) or any other way ?

Thanks !

Comment: Display different div only if the previous one is filled. That's a great way

Comment: Also validate all previous and current step data on each step submission.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

URL::previous() will return the referrer url.
If you want to prevent that they use cross-site request forgeries use laravel's csrf-protection.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: so ,for example is it possible to prevent someone to go to step 3 directly with step 3's url ?

Comment: yes , i tried its possible with a `if` control like :  `if( URL::previous() == )` go to url

Comment: you can also use Sessions to make sure the user can only visit the next page.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the previous URL in blade file, please use as follows:

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

For current path use as follows accordingly if the current path is:

`Example: http://localhost:8000/brand/campaign/create/about`

```
request()->Fullurl(); 
// http://localhost:8000/brand/campaign/create/about 

request()->URL();      
// http://localhost:8000/brand/campaign/create/about 

request()->root();     
// http://localhost:8000 

request()->path();     
// brand/campaign/create/about
```